# VBA script or something else to automatically pushes a button

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to make a VBA script or something else that automatically pushes a button with a macro in it?

For example, if the cell (1:I) has WAAR in it, that the button (planning maken) is pushed automatically (see image)?

It doesn't have to be this way, if you know something else it's fine too.

[image]

Comment: Yes, there is way. What you tried by yourself?

Comment: What should `cell (1:I)` be?

Comment: I tried the code: 

the Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$I$1" And Target.Value = "TRUE" Then
        Application.Run ("Planning_maken")
    End If
End Sub

When I put the code in the sheet and start running the code it asked me to select a macro. Then I click on me macro Planning_maken en start running te macro. then the macro starts running for one time. But it isn't running automatically. When I delete the TRUE ( WAAR is the dutch word for TRUE) and type TRUE in (I;1) nothing happens.

Comment: The button isn't an ActiveX control, it is a form control. 
the macro Planning_maken =  

Sub Planning_maken()
'
' Planning_maken Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.Range("$B$15:$E$100").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=RGB(0, _
        176, 80), Operator:=xlFilterFontColor
End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to "push a button" automatically.

However, I imagine that the code behind the "push button" is something like:

```
Sub CommandButton_Click(Target as Range)
...
End Sub
```

What you can do, is create a macro that launches this procedure, but then you have the problem, when would anybody launch that macro? There, you have provided the answer (more or less) yourself: when cell "I1" gets a certain value. This, however, is not possible: you cannot declare a macro to be launched when a cell gets a certain value.
But: you can launch a macro when any cell is changed, it works as follows:

[image]

What does this all mean?

In the VBA project editor (left pane), you need to select your sheet, and in the source code editor, you need to go for "Worksheet" and "Change", like this you have the event which is called whenever some value changes in your worksheet.

The code itself looks as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Row = 1 And Target.Column = 9 And Target.Value = True Then
    CommandButton_Click (...)
  End If
End Sub
```

This means that the macro will always be launched, but you only want something to happen when:

```
Target.Row    = 1    (which correspond with cell "I1")
Target.Column = 9    (which corresponds with cell "I1")
Target.Value  = True (which corresponds with value `WAAR`, I assume here that `WAAR` is just 
                      the Dutch translation for the boolean `True` and not some string value)
```

Comment: It is possible to trigger the button click event, it's not possible to call the event sub itself though.

Comment: The button isn't an Active Button, it is a form control. But i changed the commandbutton_click to Application.Run and it worked. so thank you!

But now I have another question, Now the macro start running when I type TRUE in (I;1). but is it possible that the macro is connected to (C;8) and when that number is changed that the macro starts running. So now the number is 696 but it is possible that when the number is changed to  700 or something else that the marco stats running.

Comment: @Ruben0888: no, you cannot link a macro to a single cell. There are macros you can trigger when any cell is changed (the typical `Worksheet_Change` event-based macros), as mentioned in the answers.

Comment: Okee clear, like you said that the marco always will be launched, but now only when something happens at row 1 en column 9. how can I change it that the macro will be launched by any change in the sheet? what adjustment do I have to do to the code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Worksheet_Change` event to trigger a macro. So, you have to make sub and call it from `Worksheet_Change` event. Sub will be same as `Planning Button` doing. Check below code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("I1")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target = "WAAR" Then
        Call MyMacro
    End If
End If
End Sub


Sub MyMacro()
    MsgBox "Value is entered to I1 cell"
End Sub
```

Comment: Keep out: as I mentioned in my answer, the value `WAAR` might be the Dutch translation of the boolean `True`, so you can't really check on the string value, but you need to check the boolean instead.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which type of button it is you need to either call the `Sub` the button is connected to, or trigger the `button_click` event procedure.

Say you have a Forms button which is calling the `Sub` Test:

```
Public Sub Test()
    MsgBox "Forms Button clicked"
End Sub
```

In your `Worksheet_Change()` procedure your code would look like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Row = 1 And Target.Column = 9 And Target.Value = True Then
        Test
    End If
End Sub
```

If you have an ActiveX button your code would look like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Row = 1 And Target.Column = 9 And Target.Value = True Then
        Sheet1.CommandButton1.Value = True ' This triggers the click event
     End If
 End Sub
```